# IPv6 address giveing syntax error in internet explorer-10 websocket

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket, ipv6

I am getting ipv6 address from server . Then i am creating url for websocket. my url looks
like

> ws://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx]:(port in decimal)

where x(0-f in hexadecimal)
this url is working fine in chrome and firefox . but in ie 10 it give syntax error .can anyone tell:-

1. -Ipv6 is supporting in ie -10
2. -if it is supporting what extra have to be done for supporting ipv6

Comment: I get the same "SyntaxError" error in IE 10 trying to connect to the IPv6 version of localhost (e.g. ws://[::1]:8088). It works in all other major browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by using "Literal IPv6 addresses in UNC path names" .
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

Comment: But why is this ugly hack required for a ws:// connection when the regular ipv6 colon-syntax url works fine for http:// connections in IE 10? Why is it that other browsers don't have this problem?