# Syntax error appears when creating websocket instance with IPv6 address

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket

Syntax error appears when creating websocket instance (only happen only on IE) with IPv6 address

I tried to use Literal IPv6 addresses in UNC path names as guide below 
[IPv6 address giveing syntax error in internet explorer-10 websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157910/ipv6-address-giveing-syntax-error-in-internet-explorer-10-websocket)

http://2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348
ws://2001-db8-85a3-8d3-1319-8a2e-370-7348.ipv6-literal.net/websocket

Syntax error on IE does not appear but Websocket connection is not established. I check and see that Session was missed when websocket client sends request to establish connection(Happen on Firefox and IE).

Comment: Websocket works fine when I used Literal IPv6 addresses for http and ws. But user usually use normal format of IPv6, http works file but ws.